# Mysql query com agrupamento por dia e faixa de horário

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Boa tarde. estou montando uma página com relatórios baseado na quantidade de vendas que um bar fez.

só que exite um problema. Preciso gerar um relatório de vendas por dia ate ai consegui fazendo o agrupamento `"SELECT count(id) total, DATE(data_abertura) abertura from vendas group by abertura limit 15";`

só que isso esta retornando errado pelo seguinte motivo que o bar abre dia 19 por ex e só vai fechar dia 20 então uma comanda pode ser aberta dia 20 meia noite e meia sendo que o bar abriu dia 19 e essa venda deveria ser computada como dia 19.

Alguma dica sobre logica ou query de como resolver este impasse?

Comment: Sua data ta no formato datetime correto ? se sim:  SELECT count(id) total, DATE(data_abertura) abertura FROM vendas WHERE hora_da_comanda > data_do_dia_hora_de_abertua AND hora_da_comanda < data_do_dia_mais_um_dia_hora_de_fechamento GROUP BY abertura limit 15

Comment: @Jasar Orion O AnthraxisBR creio que possa esta certo, mas se pudermos criar uma tabela com uma única linha  DATA que será populada na ABERTURA do sistema, então TODAS as vendas pegariam a data dessa tabela e caso fosse necessário, criaria outro campo data na tabela vendas para guardar a DATA real que foi feito o pedido. São sugestões :)  Espero que possam jogar alguma luz ou nova direção na resolução do seu problema :)

Comment: Acredito que o que você quer fazer é calcular pela data do caixa, mais uma coluna com o código do caixa resolveria o problema.

Comment: entendi entao nao tem essa tabela no db para armazenar a data. pensei no seguinte vou forçar um date time especifico pro serv tipo 12 horas menos dai o dia do cara nao começa nas 00 e sim meio dia. so fazendo isso ja resolveria.